# What is the difference between the PS3 and PS4 versions of Watch Dogs?

Tags: ps3, ps4, version-differences, watch-dogs

I am thinking on buying the PS33 version but not sure how different it is from the PS4 version.

Are the differences just graphical or is there any content difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

Two main differences :
First one is graphical, PS4 version is slightly enhanced visually.
Second one, PS4 version only works on PS4, PS3 version only works on PS3
(Worth mentioning there is no retro/post-compatibility)